# ASP.Net Deployment Error: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a asp.net website in .Net 4.0 that runs fine in our staging environment. When we moved it into production we are getting following error

Server Error in '/mysite' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'SupportSite.UI' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. 
Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SupportSite.UI' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

I assume it is a security issue. It is deployed using **IIS WAS** settings.

1. What are the users for whom I need to grant permission (and on what all folders)?
2. What is the user corresponding to aspnet_wp.exe or w3wp.exe?

REFERENCES

1. [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. The issue is random, but after it happens once, it continues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096225/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access-is-denied-th)
2. [Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754626/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-telerik-web-ui-or-one-of-its-dependencies)
3. [ApplicationPoolIdentity permissions on Temporary Asp.Net files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996556/applicationpoolidentity-permissions-on-temporary-asp-net-files)
4. [could not load file or assembly, Tried all solution on net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539323/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-tried-all-solution-on-net)

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant read permission for the **lib** folder to **IIS_IUSRS** account.

Comment: Don't I need to grant permission on Temporary ASP.NET Files?

Comment: no, the IIS_IUSRS account by default has full access to that folder

Answer (score 1):

I asume your using IIS 7.5..

You have two choices: Adding your library to GAC, or give read permissions to the application pool account.

See this about app pool account permissions:
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities